# Android: Customization in SearchView Widget

Tags: android, user-interface, searchview

I want to change the color of the search Icon, but Not able to do that. Can someone suggest to me how to do that?

This is the code I'm using:

```
                <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/scheme_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Type Scheme Name"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/pluswhite">

            </SearchView>
```

Using this I'm getting the following output:

[image]

I want to make the search icon and the divider's color white.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom drawable, so it could be any color you need:

```
<SearchView
..
android:searchIcon="@drawable/customIcon">
..
</SearchView>
```

In this case the line's color will be white, just change the id's

```
private void customizeSearchView() {
        int searchTextId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        EditText searchBox = ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchTextId));
        searchBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        searchBox.getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int search_plateId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
        View mSearchPlate = ((View) searchView.findViewById(search_plateId));
        mSearchPlate.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        int searchCloseImageId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
        ImageView searchClose = ((ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchCloseImageId));// change color
        searchClose.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Comment: I think we need something else to change the line's color. Using this code, it is changing the color of the whole area.

Comment: Can you edit your post and put the whole xml? With your toolbar at least if you are using one

Comment: Also, why don't you try using <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView> so you can use a custom style and also get rid of that line that it's not the best imo